# Why Bundler can't find the proper gem version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I try update Rails version, Bundler returns:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rake":
  In Gemfile:
    rake (= 10.5)

    annotate was resolved to 2.7.5, which depends on
      rake (>= 10.4, < 13.0)

    rails (= 6.1) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      railties (= 6.1.0) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
        rake (>= 0.8.7)
```

I'm trying to understand why Bundler can't just take 10.5 Rake version ?

`10.5` && `>= 10.4, < 13.0` && `>= 0.8.7`

It looks that all criteria are met for `10.5` but Bundler just doesn't use this version, so wondering why ?

Comment: You sure the rake is 10.5 in the lockfile?  In my 6.0 rails projects it is 13.0.1.

Comment: yes,  rake (= 10.5)
but even if it were so I could imagine that Bundler should inform me about that somehow. What I have now is message about dependencies which is in contrary.

Comment: please add your gemfile and lock file